# What's a recipe repair?

Tags: phrase-meaning, food

I read on https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic:

> Recipe comprehension, improvement, and repairs

What's a recipe repair? I can't find that concept on Google.

Comment: You can't find **recipe repair** on Google because it's not an established collocation. But *in context*, the meaning should be obvious (what to do if certain *specific* "predictable" things go wrong with your cooking). This is just normal use of English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers might be obvious to you, but two out of the three answers provide a different meaning (and the third answer doesn't provide any meaning).

Comment: David's answer simply says it's not an established collocation and nothing more. Laurel's answer says the same, but agrees with me that it's "how to fix a dish that's already gone wrong". I'm guessing the other answer is from a non-native speaker, since ***revision*** is hardly a synonym of ***repair***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Laurel's answer also suggests the meaning "advice on how to alter/specify a recipe in advance"

Comment: Is that really significant? Given *it's not an established collocation*, you have to exercise *some* creative interpretation to assign it a meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "exercise some creative interpretation to assign it a meaning. " sounds like a task better executed by a native speaker

Comment: Compréhension, amélioration et réparations de recettes **pour chefs de cuisine avisés.** Evidemment, cela ne marche pas pour les commis...

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming they are using repair as a synonym of revision.

Answer (score 1):

Since the text is part of the help center for cooking.stackexchange.com, it mightn be better to ask on their meta site, https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/ for a more specific answer.

I agree that "recipe repair" is not a usual phrase.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I've heard this phrase before, but it seems to mean either advice on how to alter/specify a recipe in advance or how to fix a dish that's already gone wrong (for example, due to bad measurements). Here are some examples:

- [recipe repair? :( How to neutralize too much parsley?](https://cooking.livejournal.com/7446016.html?)
- [Lentil, Beet and Tahini Salad](https://cre8ov.com/2016/06/lentil-beet-tahini-salad/):

  > It was mostly beets with a smattering of lentils. I wanted more delicious lentils. So I hacked the recipe. I thought you would be interested in the process of me developing a recipe so here’s what I did to it. […list of changes…] I[t] is what I really call a recipe repair.

And *repair* alone in a food context:

- > Is there anyway to repair [salty pie dough](https://cooking.livejournal.com/8216130.html?)?
- [What can I do to repair too salty fried pork chops?](https://recipes.food.narkive.com/oi8VLiCP/what-can-i-do-to-repair-too-salty-fried-pork-chops)

Answer (score 1):

The tagline says "repairs"  because **it's shorthand** for *“Different ways to **repair mistakes** in cooking”* or “*Questions **about *repairs* for dishes** that go wrong”*.

Let's say you accidentally add salt instead of confectioner sugar in your whipped cream, what can you do to save it? Is it [salvageable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salvageable#:%7E:text=Capable%20of%20being%20salvaged%2C%20saved,keeping%20rather%20discarding%20or%20replacing.)? Is there an easy *repair* (i.e. a solution)?

> As a general rule, Claire Saffitz, associate food editor, says to start with one tablespoon of sugar per cup of cream and increase to two for a sweeter whipped cream. Although we always advocate a pinch of salt in our baking, whipped cream is the exception to this rule. Even the tiniest pinch will make whipped cream taste, well, salty.

Comment: Yes, but these are mistakes in recipes, not necessarily in cooking.

Comment: @Lambie I had't thought of that but established classic recipes, in cookery books and online, don't usually contain mistakes. They've been tested over and over again. It's the cooks who commit "errors" by not following the right measurements or procedure, e.g is it possible to fix (repair) a mayonnaise that has split?

Comment: I have no idea, I only know it is here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic :)